# Using the \Question environment as in MWE, can the question number be aligned with the top of the table?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{book}
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage{newtxmath} % darkens and boldens the Greek fonts
\usepackage{setspace} % 
\usepackage{enumerate} % 
\usepackage{enumitem} %
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl} % canged to just colortbl
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{newunicodechar} % unit of degree
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} % 
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{textcomp} %
\usepackage[lastexercise, answerdelayed]{exercise}
%
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter] % Reset exercise counter every chapter
\renewcounter{Answer}[chapter]
\newcounter{Problem}[chapter]
%
\graphicspath{ {book_questions/images/} }
%
\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.2}
\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_02_exer_02},name={A question needing a diagram}]

\Question{A photograph measuring \hspace{0.8pt}$8$\hspace{0.8pt}cm \hspace{0.8pt}by \hspace{0.8pt}$6$\hspace{0.8pt}cm \hspace{0.8pt}is enlarged so the the area is doubled\hspace{0.8pt}. \\ Find the dimensions of the enlargement\hspace{0.6pt}.}

\Question{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\parbox{0.55\textwidth}{

\noindent This layout produces a question number

\noindent which is centred vertically relative to the

\noindent table (or the figure).\vspace{6pt}

\noindent Can the the numbering be forced to be level 

\noindent with the first line of text as in the previous

\noindent question?
}
&
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../my_book/book_questions/fig_01_piston_accel}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular} }

\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could post a full compilable code?

Comment: I cannot see how to add more code.

Comment: Bernard@ I cannot see how to add more code.

Comment: Do you think the posted code is compilable, as is?

Comment: Bernard@ No - I do have the full code but I don't know how to enter it.

Comment: We need at least the preamble, at least the part of the preamble which is necessary to compile (where is `\Question` defined, for instance), and `\begin{document}`  `\end{document}`. You can edit your own post and add it to the code.

Comment: Bernard@ Code now added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71589/discussion-between-keith77777-and-bernard).

Comment: Bernard@ Many thanks for your answer and for the general comments on the use of packages.  I have two observations to make: it appears that the text on the left column of the table cannot be wrapped - it has to be broken into individual paragraphs.  The removal of the package \colortbl caused big problems and I had to abandon that to make progress, but it may be that my other packages are conflicting.  Otherwise perfect.

Comment: You don't have to break lines into individual paragraphs since the column has `p` type. I've just mofofoed the code so there are no more thes individual paragraphs, and as you can see it works. As to the conflict with `xcolor` (probably already loaded by another package), give the options as options to  `\documentclass`, which pass them on to `xcolor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code with `adjustbox` and the `valign` key. I  removed from your code `colortbl`, which is loaded by `xcolor` with option `[table]`. Note the language options of `babel`, since version `3.10` should be loaded with the document class, to ensure all language-dependent packages be aware of the  language(s) of the document. Also, `enumerate` shouldn't be loaded with `enumitem`. As enumitem can do everything enumerate does (and more…), I removed it.

```
\documentclass[english, table, demo]{book}
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %
\usepackage{babel} %
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage{newtxmath} % darkens and boldens the Greek fonts
\usepackage{setspace} %
\usepackage{enumitem} %
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar} % unit of degree
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, textwidth=132mm, lmargin=12.5mm, rmargin=12.5mm, bindingoffset=12.5mm, noheadfoot, nomarginpar, showframe, showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{textcomp} %
\usepackage[lastexercise, answerdelayed]{exercise}
%
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter] % Reset exercise counter every chapter
\renewcounter{Answer}[chapter]
\newcounter{Problem}[chapter]
%
\graphicspath{ {book_questions/images/} }
%
\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.2}
\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_02_exer_02},name={A question needing a diagram}]

\Question{A photograph measuring \hspace{0.8pt}$8$\hspace{0.8pt}cm \hspace{0.8pt}by \hspace{0.8pt}$6$\hspace{0.8pt}cm \hspace{0.8pt}is enlarged so the the area is doubled\hspace{0.8pt}. \\ Find the dimensions of the enlargement\hspace{0.6pt}.}

\Question{
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.55\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}@{}}
\everypar{\noindent}
 This layout produces a question number which is centred vertically relative to the table (or the figure).\vspace{6pt}

 Can the the numbering be forced to be level with the first line of text as in the previous question?
&
        \adjincludegraphics[width=1\linewidth, valign = t, raise = -1.2ex]{../my_book/book_questions/fig_01_piston_accel}
\end{tabular} }

\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are welcome. i try to compile your answer but i receive error(s): "`lastexercise` undefined in family ex. ". i suspect that in my installation of `miktex` is missing something (regardless that miktex load missing files "on the fly"). how to find what?

Comment: @Zarko: I have no idea. I compiled on a MiKTeX, and had no problem (only some minor overfull hboxes or fontsize warnings). The package was already installed on my  system.